# UML template function modelling in enterprise architect

Tags: function, templates, enterprise-architect

I would like to model a template funcion within a class diagram  in enterprise architect. For example,

```html
template<typename T> T foo(CMyClass<T> arg);
```

I guess it' something like creating a stereotype "template" but the enterprise architect does not mention this case anywhere.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Looking for the same, I know UML provides special drawing for templates, but I did not found how in EA.

Comment: What do you try to achieve with this modelling? Do you plan to generate source code? If so, do you want to use EA built-in code generator or you are trying to write your own one?